# BlueZ map-client and iOS 8.x device

Tags: ios, bluez

I am attempting to use the supplied map-client in BlueZ 5.30 to read the SMS inbox from an iPhone running iOS 8.3

When I run the map-client with the phone's address I can use calls such as `-l` to see the directory listings and through repeated `-c` calls I've worked out that the messages should be in `/telecom/msg/inbox`.

However, I can never see any messages in this folder when called `-L` despite there being lots in the phones Message app. I've also tried sending a message to the phone and asking for the folder, but nothing appears - I always get an empty python list:

```
{}
```

Has anyone else managed to use BlueZ map-client to read an iOS device's messages?

Answer (score 1):

To view messages in the inbox, first we have to change the directory to the standard path /telecom/msg/inbox. 
so ./map-client -d BD_ADDRS -c /telecom/msg/inbox -L LS_MSG
similarly for outbox, sent, draft, deleted

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and wound up here so I'll post for the benefit of anyone else who does the same:

The `LS_MSG` argument to `-L` is treated as the folder to read, so to read the inbox the command would be:

```
./map-client -d BD_ADDRS -c /telecom/msg -L inbox
```

This wasn't at all clear to me from the `./map-client --help` output, so I ended up reading the source code to figure it out.